# Using Google Maps Places Library with Custom Data

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Semi-Simple question here; I am building a simple mobile web application and want to be able to store different businesses in a database along with custom information (reviews, ratings, etc).

I also want users to be able to find these businesses around them, say within a radius. I've been looking into Google's [`Places`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) Library and this seems to  accomplish that well - particularly the Radar Search.

My question is; is it feasible to combine the concepts? For example if I fetch 10 different businesses around me through `Places`' API, could I simultaneously fetch the data that I've stored about each business? (These locations won't necessarily be registered on Google Maps nor do I want to use any of Map's data).

Let's look at a possible scenario: Say I get 3 locations returned from the Radar Search

```
[
  {location1: {lat: 38.434, long: 34.439, ...}}, // I'm assuming a response would be
  {location2: {lat: 38.549, long: 34.998, ...}}, // something like this
  {location3: {lat: 38.684, long: 34.834, ...}}
]
```

Conceptually, how should my app retrieve data from my database based on this response? Is lat/long a reliable lookup criteria?

I want to make sure that what I'm going for is a plausible solution for my application - has anyone done a similar task to this?

Thanks for any help/feedback/critique!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to have the business marker with in the place of interest.

1>The database should contain the location (lat,lng) together with business type and other data

2>In the search page there has to be input for place of interest(taking lat,lng) where business has to be searched with type of business and other filter

3> taking the interest area(lat,lng) get all business within [radius](http://spinczyk.net/blog/2009/10/04/radius-search-with-google-maps-and-mysql/) make a query.

4> the result of the query is used to populate the queried business with in radius of interest

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/8njd8qnb/) for demonstration with static data for default all places with in radius.

`all_locations` should come from databsae

Js code

```
var map = null;
var radius_circle;
var markers_on_map = [];
var geocoder;
var infowindow;

//all_locations is just a sample, you will probably load those from database
var all_locations = [{
  type: "Restaurant",
  name: "Restaurant 1",
  lat: 40.723080,
  lng: -73.984340
}, {
  type: "School",
  name: "School 1",
  lat: 40.724705,
  lng: -73.986611
}, {
  type: "School",
  name: "School 2",
  lat: 40.724165,
  lng: -73.983883
}, {
  type: "Restaurant",
  name: "Restaurant 2",
  lat: 40.721819,
  lng: -73.991358
}, {
  type: "School",
  name: "School 3",
  lat: 40.732056,
  lng: -73.998683
}];

//initialize map on document ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.723080, -73.984340); //you can use any location as center on map startup
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    if (infowindow) {
      infowindow.setMap(null);
      infowindow = null;
    }
  });
});

function showCloseLocations() {
  var i;
  var radius_km = $('#radius_km').val();
  var address = $('#address').val();

  //remove all radii and markers from map before displaying new ones
  if (radius_circle) {
    radius_circle.setMap(null);
    radius_circle = null;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < markers_on_map.length; i++) {
    if (markers_on_map[i]) {
      markers_on_map[i].setMap(null);
      markers_on_map[i] = null;
    }
  }

  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          var address_lat_lng = results[0].geometry.location;
          radius_circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: address_lat_lng,
            radius: radius_km * 1000,
            clickable: false,
            map: map
          });
          if (radius_circle) map.fitBounds(radius_circle.getBounds());
          for (var j = 0; j < all_locations.length; j++) {
            (function(location) {
              var marker_lat_lng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng);
              var distance_from_location = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(address_lat_lng, marker_lat_lng); //distance in meters between your location and the marker
              if (distance_from_location <= radius_km * 1000) {
                var new_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: marker_lat_lng,
                  map: map,
                  title: location.name
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(new_marker, 'click', function() {
                  if (infowindow) {
                    infowindow.setMap(null);
                    infowindow = null;
                  }
                  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: '<div style="color:red">' + location.name + '</div>' + " is " + distance_from_location + " meters from my location",
                    size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50),
                    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30),
                    position: marker_lat_lng,
                    map: map
                  });
                });
                markers_on_map.push(new_marker);
              }
            })(all_locations[j]);
          }
        } else {
          alert("No results found while geocoding!");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Html

```
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
  <input id="address" value="Second Steet, New York" placeholder="Input Address" />
  <select id="radius_km">
    <option value=1>1km</option>
    <option value=2>2km</option>
    <option value=5>5km</option>
    <option value=30>30km</option>
  </select>
  <button onClick="showCloseLocations()">Show Locations In Radius</button>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:300px;">
</body>
```

Hope this gives enough idea

**Sorry for bad english**

**Disclaimer**
code inside fiddle is from [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37088634/3898339)